# pgfplots decimal separator for extra ticks

Tags: pgfplots

I'm trying to format *all* y tick labels in a `pgfplots` plot so that comma is the decimal separator. What I've tried is:

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat = 1.12}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[axis lines = center, xlabel = {$x$}, ylabel = {$f(x)$},
     /pgf/number format/.cd, use comma, 
    extra y ticks = {8.25}, extra y tick labels = {$\theta = 8.25$}]
    \addplot [domain = 0:8] {x^2}; 
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

which gives

[image: MWE output PDF]

I'd also like the decimal separators to be aligned properly (in case other y ticks use one) even with the `\theta =` part being present.

Using `\pgfmathprintnumber{8.25}` gives me the correct decimal separator (,) but I can't get the `\theta =` positioned properly.

Answer (score 2):

If all the `extra y ticks` should have `\theta =` before the number, you can use

```
extra y tick label = {$\theta = \pgfmathprintnumber{\tick}$}
```

instead of the `extra y tick labels`. Or if it's just the one, you could  modify your code to `extra y tick labels = {$\theta = \pgfmathprintnumber{8.25}$}`.

Commas will line up given that you've set the same precision for all the ticklabels, see second example.

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat = 1.12}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[
    axis lines = center,
    xlabel = {$x$},
    ylabel = {$f(x)$},
    /pgf/number format/.cd, use comma,
    extra y ticks = {8.25,28.45},
    extra y tick label = {$\theta = \pgfmathprintnumber{\tick}$},
    ]
    \addplot [domain = 0:8] {x^2}; 
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[
    axis lines = center,
    xlabel = {$x$},
    ylabel = {$f(x)$},
    /pgf/number format/.cd, use comma,
    extra y ticks = {8.25,28.4},
    extra y tick label = {$\theta = \pgfmathprintnumber{\tick}$},
    yticklabel style={/pgf/number format/.cd,
                      fixed,fixed zerofill,precision=2}
    ]
    \addplot [domain = 0:8] {x^2}; 
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]